# How to disable adsense for this error page

Tags: 6

I want to disable adsense ads for this url: http://www.indiacustomercare.com/node/167/submission/274

which is accessible only to the admin.

How can I do it for my D6 site?

Answer (score 2):

use the [Adsense](http://drupal.org/project/adsense) module, you can specify pages where to display it or not to display it using :

Show AdSense on specific pages:

- Show on every page except the listed pages.
- Show on only the listed pages.
- Show if the following PHP code returns TRUE (PHP-mode, experts only).